# How to shuffle a Rubik's cube?

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\begin{document}

\newarray\colors
\readarray{colors}{red&red&red&red&red&red&red&red&yellow&yellow&yellow&yellow&yellow&yellow&yellow&yellow&yellow&orange&orange&orange&orange&orange&orange&orange&orange&orange&green&green&green&green&green&green&green&green&green&blue&blue&blue&blue&blue&blue&blue&blue&blue}

\edef\colorfaces{}%
\multido{\i=0+1}{57}{%
\checkcolors(\i)
\xdef\colorfaces{\colorfaces\i\space(\cachedata)\space}}
%
\def\figure#1#2{%
\psset{viewpoint=120 50 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\psSolid[a=8,object=cube,ngrid=3,%
fcol=\colorfaces%
,Rot#2=-#1\space]%
\end{pspicture}
}
\multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\figure{\iA}{X}}
\multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\figure{\iA}{Y}}
\multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\figure{\iA}{Z}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:

1. Is there an another way without using the package arrayjob?
2. How to get the random color for it?

Thanks.

Comment: As for 2.: you are already loading `pgf`, so you have already a built in way to get a random item. Just add `\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{colors}{{red}{red}{red}{red}{red}{red}{red}{red}{yellow}{yellow}{yellow}{yellow}{yellow}{yellow}{yellow}{yellow}{yellow}{orange}{orange}{orange}{orange}{orange}{orange}{orange}{orange}{orange}{green}{green}{green}{green}{green}{green}{green}{green}{green}{blue}{blue}{blue}{blue}{blue}{blue}{blue}{blue}{blue}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{colors}
\typeout{\c}` to your code.

Comment: It occurred to me that random colors may not be a good idea.  There are six colors, eight corners and eight edges.  Each edge has a unique combination of 2 colors, and each corner has a unique combination of 3 colors, of which each color is used in precisely 4 corners and 4 edges.  And each of 6 centers has a different color.  What you really need is a random sort of the different components.

Comment: Because the colors are not freely randomized but they  must follow some rules, I think I need to change the title to be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=120 50 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\pstVerb{/Colors [(red)(yellow)(orange)(green)(blue)] def }
\def\figure#1#2{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
        \psSolid[a=8,object=cube,ngrid=3,%
        fcol= 
           0 1 8 { Colors Rand 4.5 mul cvi get } for  
           9 1 17 { Colors Rand 4.5 mul cvi get } for  
           18 1 26 { Colors Rand 4.5 mul cvi get } for  
           27 1 35 { Colors Rand 4.5 mul cvi get } for  
           36 1 44 { Colors Rand 4.5 mul cvi get } for  
           45 1 53 { Colors Rand 4.5 mul cvi get } for,
        Rot#2=-#1\space]%
        \end{pspicture}
    }
    \multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\figure{\iA}{X}}
    \multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\figure{\iA}{Y}}
    \multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\figure{\iA}{Z}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
 0 1 8 {      from 0 to 8 with step 1 do
            put the loop variable on the stack
 Colors.    Load Color array 
 Rand       get a random number between 0 and 1
 4.5 mul    between 0 and 4.5
 cvi        between 0 and 4
 get        load color with random number
 } for.     end of for loop
```

Every square has a corresponding number 0 .. 53 which can be used
for color setting:  0 (red) 1 (green) ... and so on. see pages 38 ff of
the documentation.

The same for complete faces:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=120 50 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50}
\pstVerb{/Colors [(red)(yellow)(orange)(green)(blue)] def }
\def\figure#1#2{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
        \psSolid[a=8,object=cube,ngrid=3,%
        fcol= 
           0 1 8 { (red) } for  
           9 1 17 { (green) } for  
           18 1 26 { (blue) } for  
           27 1 35 { (orange) } for  
           36 1 44 { (yellow) } for  
           45 1 53 { (cyan) } for,
        Rot#2=-#1\space]%
        \end{pspicture}
    }
    \multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\figure{\iA}{X}}
    \multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\figure{\iA}{Y}}
    \multido{\iA=0+10}{36}{\figure{\iA}{Z}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please to answer the first question. Your code(PostScript language) is new with me...

Comment: see edited answer ...

Comment: Oh, you misunderstood me. I mean that you can rewrite my code as the smart way.( my figure only 6 colors). The second question is not important. :-) And of course thanks for your expansion..

Comment: And I just check pages 38 of the documentation BUT there is no anything as you can see. :-)

Comment: I see only 5 colors. pages 38ff show anything about colors.

Comment: Oh, white is by default. But I do not know they are in front of red... or behind blue :-)) And what does " 38ff " mean? Where is it?

Comment: ff and the following pages ...

Comment: A small curiousity, I can find _cvi_,_get_,_Rand_ (PS language) in where? :-)

Comment: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/ps.html